# Do mongodb completely lock write to database while doing createIndex operation and mongodump?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, locking, database

Just want to know if my database has about 50 queries per sec in production, will it still be able to run normally while do these operation?

My server info is:

- Normal replica 2 machine with no sharding.
- Just use capped collection for logging purpose only. No read. It's write heavy.
- 8GB of RAM

Comment: With more detail, this might be a better fit for dba.stackexchange.com. You'd need to add some information about the types of queries, server hardware, RAM, sharding needs, etc.

Comment: added more info as your suggestion.

Comment: But, what's your programming question? You need to build a proof of concept to validate your requirements. Stackoverflow isn't a good fit for your question as it currently stands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation [1] about concurrency is quite clear:

"When a read lock exists, many read operations may use this lock. However, when a write lock exists, a single write operation holds the lock exclusively, and no other read or write operations may share the lock."

Insert, update, and delete operations use a write lock.

Basically that means all you inserts will happen sequentially, so it's a matter of how fast Mongo writes the data.

[1] http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/#which-administrative-commands-lock-the-database

Comment: Didn't actually answer my question since I'm asking about createindex and mongodump. However, thanks for the link. Also, what about mongodump?